# MacBook Air M1 with ultrawide monitor

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, display

I have a 13” MacBook Air M1 laptop, and I'm planning to buy a 35” ultrawide monitor for work. Any issues or concerns to be aware of before buying one??

Also, I will be using Citrix workspace to connect to my work which is a Windows machine. Will I be able to sync the Apple keyboard with the Windows one when using an external display? Any suggestions will help.

Comment: It's the resolution that's the important factor, not the physical size of the screen. There are 3840 x 2160 displays at 24 inches wide, and you can also get 32 inch screens that are only 1920 x 1080...!! The computer just cares about how many pixels it has to push. (But yeah, the MBA should cope with any display on the market.)

Comment: Depends on your work.  Fonts will be blurry compared with MBA's display, unless it is high resolution. I would likely hate it!

Comment: @Gilby I'm referring to "whether it will work". But I agree: I certainly wouldn't get a 1080p 32" display....!!!

Answer (score 4):

I don’t expect any issues. We tested the M1 macs with Apple Pro Display 6016 by 3384 pixels (20.4 million pixels) and it’s amazing and fast. Dell, LG are also good workhorses.

- Citrix, TeamViewer, ARD, VNC, RDC all work very well and crisply.

We prefer these connections for speed, clarity and robustness.

- Thunderbolt > USB-C > DisplayPort > HDMI > USB > DisplayLink

HDMI and lower have issues that are easy to come across and/or frustrating to fix or diagnose for work needs IMO. If you’re making money with this setup, stay to the left of HDMI unless your support team has specific cables and models they support.

Comment: P.S. we didn’t buy the XDR but had one to test for reasons…. They are absolute beasts. I think we will spring for some of the new studio displays though, and continue with lots of Dell and LG for most workstations

Answer (score 0):

M1 Air has no issues displaying resolutions up to 5120*1440 on a 49 inch ultrawide or 5120x2160 on 5k2k screens.

Make sure to pick up a monitor with USB-C connector and at least 65W power delivery.

As for Citrix and remote access, I don't have experience. Having said that, if Citrix is an app on a Mac, it should work with whatever you connect to your mac.